# How to reconstruct the return shape of a generic method which has generic return type?

Tags: c#, generics, tuples, c#-10.0

I have a generic method called `Transfer` which returns a generic type too. In the body of `Transfer`, I do some processing and get `MessageBundle` object. How Can I reconstruct the return type of `Transfer` (using `MessageBundle` object) in a generic way?

I can only make it work in non-generic way.

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this works
            var test = Transfer<(string? Result, string? Error)>();
            
            //???
            var test = Transfer<(int? Result, string? Error)>();
            var test = Transfer<(bool? Result, string? Error)>();
            var test = Transfer<(object? Result, string? Error)>();
        }

        public static U Transfer<U>()
        {
            //getting MessageBundle object
            var bundle = new MessageBundle
            {
                Result = "hi",
                Error = null
            };

            //How to reconstruct in generic way?
            (string? Result, string? Error) response = (bundle.Result as string, bundle.Error);

            return (U)Convert.ChangeType(response, typeof(U));
        }
    }

    public class MessageBundle
    {
        public string? Error { get; set; }
        public object? Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**: I have no control over the signature of `Transfer` method.

**Edit 2**: The shape of `U` (`Transfer` method) will be a tuple of two elements (`Error` is always a string while `Result` can vary)

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with construction and reconstruction. What type are you trying to return? The compiler needs to know at compile time, even if it's through type constraints like `where U:ISomeInterface` or `U:SomeBaseClass` or `U:struct`

Comment: Right now even a human couldn't guess what you're trying to do. You can't cast one arbitrary type into another. Implicit casts work if one type *is* an instance of the other, or an implicit conversion operator is defined. The same holds for explicit casts.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to generically convert a string tuple to a tuple of arbitrary types, which is not possible with `ChangeType`. You may need to define `Transfer` as a generic method with two types instead of a tuple.

Comment: If you wan to implement a Result type like F#, Go or Rust, you need a `Result<T> { public T? Result {get;set;} public string? Error {get;set;}}` at least. If you want to take a `Result<T>` and return a `Result<U>` then either T is a U, or you need a function to convert from one to the other

Comment: @DStanley that string tuple is just an example. The big limitation is that I have no control over the signature of `Transfer ` method.

Comment: Well I wish you said that when you first made the post, before I went through all the effort to make my answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry man. Just edited the post.

Comment: Regardless, you can't use `ChangeType` to convert the types of a tuple. If you can't change the signature of `Transfer` you're going to have to use some nasty reflection code to get the source/dest types and convert each value separately.

Comment: @DStanley that's most probably the way. but how?

Comment: Is the intent do deserialize the string? Like Jsons [Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm)? Or use a [typeconverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=net-6.0) ? Regardless, that will only work if your result-string actually represent the object of the generic type. You cannot convert an arbitrary string to any arbitrary object type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance that `U` will be a tuple of 2 items but cannot change the signature of `public static U Transfer<U>()` **in any way** (even by adding an [`ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netcore-3.1) constraint), you will need to use reflection to construct the tuple.  And assuming that the first tuple parameter is a .NET primitive of some sort and that the value of `Result` is its string representation, you can use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0) to convert the string value to the final value.

One way to do this would be:

```
if (!typeof(ITuple).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(U))  // Assert it's a tuple
    || !(typeof(U).IsGenericType && typeof(U).GetGenericArguments() is var arguments && arguments.Length == 2) // Assert it has exactly two generic parameters
    || arguments[1] != typeof(string)) // Assert that the second parameter is a string
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unexpected type {0}", typeof(U)));

var tuple = (U)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), 
                                        bundle.Result == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(bundle.Result, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(arguments[0]) ?? arguments[0]), 
                                        bundle.Error)!;
```

Notes:

- You don't specify what should happen in the event the `Result` conversion fails, e.g. you are specifying an integer type for `Result` but the value is `"hi"`.  The implementation above will throw an exception from within `Convert.ChangeType()` if this happens.
- You also don't specify what should happen when the `Result` corresponds to some complex object that does not implement [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0).  The implementation above will also throw an exception in such a case.
- [`Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0#system-convert-changetype(system-object-system-type)) uses the current culture to do the conversion.  If you want to use the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0) (e.g. because you are deserializing a value received over the wire) use [`ChangeType(Object, Type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0#system-convert-changetype(system-object-system-type-system-iformatprovider)):

  ```
    var tuple = (U)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), 
                                            bundle.Result == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(bundle.Result, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(arguments[0]) ?? arguments[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                                            bundle.Error)!;
  ```
- You really should rethink this design.  Using reflection in this manner eliminates almost all compile-time checking for code correctness.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SAcsGQ).